# RHEL 5: Unable to apply patch

Tags: linux, rhel

I was following this WebSite for installing repcache on Memcached1.4.5

http://forums.famillecollet.com/viewtopic.php?id=252

Initially i downloaded this repcached-2.3-1.4.5.patch.gz

I am using RHEL5

Then i run

```
gunzip repcached-2.3-1.4.5.patch.gz
```

It generated a file named repcached-2.3-1.4.5.patch

Then executed

```
patch -p1 -i repcached-2.3-1.4.5.patch
```

**It started Producing this**

```
patching file ChangeLog.repcached
can't find file to patch at input line 66
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -urN memcached-1.4.5/Makefile.am memcached-1.4.5-repcached-2.3/Makefile.am
|--- memcached-1.4.5/Makefile.am        Sat Apr  3 11:07:16 2010
|+++ memcached-1.4.5-repcached-2.3/Makefile.am  Thu Feb 11 19:51:30 2010
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

please see the screen shot of the above

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see that correctly you are trying to patch the binary rpm package with a source code patch. That obviously cannot work.

You can try to do that by using the source rpm instead of the binary rpm. The source rpm is the 'source package' used to generate a binary rpm package that can be installed. It is typically called `somesoftware-xxx.src.rpm`. If you install such source rpm package you get the content unpacked under `/usr/src/packages/...`, in there is a `SOURCE` folder where you will find the memcached source archive. You must unpack that archive, apply the patch, archive the pached source and replace the archive under `SOURCE`. Or (much more elegant) you add the patch to the `spec file` which controls the build process to generate a binary rpm package from the installed source rpm package. You will find the `spec file` under `SPECS`, probably called `memcached.spec` or something. Usually there are already some patches contained, so you have a starting point.

If you have patched the source rpm package in one of the ways as described above you can build an own binary rpm package using the `rpmbuild` command, something like this: `rpmbuild -bb SPECS/memcached.spec`...